# Doctrine 2 is element in Array Coulmn prettier way?

Tags: php, arrays, doctrine

as I'm learning symfony2 and doctrine 2 only a few days I have a lot of doubts that may be silly for somebody more experienced.

I have a blog article class with 'tags' field:

```
class Article 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array")
     */
     protected $tags;
}
```

Now, I see Doctrine stores them in DB as 'longtext' type in this format:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:8:"symfony2";i:1;s:3:"php";i:2;s:8:"paradise";i:3;s:7:"symblog";}
```

Since I made a tag page which shows all articles tagged by selected tag, I need to check if blog article has this tag in its 'tags array'.

```
public function getByTag($tag)
{
    $likelyBlogs = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->select('b')
        ->where('LOWER(b.tags) LIKE :tag')
        ->setParameter('tag', '%:"'.$tag.'"%')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $likelyBlogs;
}
```

This works perfectly, however, **->where('LOWER(b.tags) LIKE :tag')** looks kinda hacky to me so I want to check if there is any other more 'natural' way to check if value exists in an array?

Comment: That looks like a bad db design :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at many-to-many relations: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional

If you really want to store your tags in the same row as your blog post you should consider using a NoSQL database like MongoDB. But in normal SQL it will be better to normalize your tables and put the tags in a single table.

Comment: As I said, I'm new and I see what you're aiming at, I have no problems making new Entity for Tags, but I just can't understand the difference between "many to many" and "one to many - many to one combined". I'm still pretty confused with these things

Comment: In your case `tags` are reusable. You can have the same tag on multiple blog posts. So in sql it is better to put them in a single table and join them to your blog post. In a many-to-many relation doctrine will create 3 tables. A `post`-Table, a `tag`-Table and a `post_to_tag`-Table. The most interesting for you is the `post_to_tag`-Table which has at least 2 columns - a `post_id` and a  `tag_id`. Post 1 can now have the tags 1, 2 and 3. Post 2 can have the tags 2, 3, 4 sharing the tag 2 and 3 with each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot, cleared it up really! Since this question isn't about how to actually achieve this ManyToMany connection with Doctrine I'll accept it and post another one with problems I stumbled upon while trying to make it work